# Levitation of a Lightbulb with Electromagnetic Induction

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I recently purchased a ''levitating lightbulb'' device where a [lightbulb is made to float above a base](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/lPvy4dPgvvo) via magnetism, but I am not sure exactly what is going on.

This device is not a Levitron, which operates on spin-stabilized magnetic levitation, whereas this one is just using changing electromagnetic fields.

The device plugs into an AC adapter, so obviously the effect is based on electromagnetic induction.  There is already a static magnet in the base before the device is switched on and once the bulb is put into a 'stable' position, the varying current creates a force which rotates the bulb to allow it to have a stable levitation and avoid Earnshaw's theorem and all that.

A part which I am not sure I understand is that there is a switch to turn on the light, but sometimes the light comes on when the bulb is brought close to the base without touching this switch.  In theory this is because the bulb is being moved and a changing magnetic field produces a current, but sometimes it switches on and sometimes it does not.

Is the concept of the Lorentz force being used, since right hand rule says that there is a force in the place perpendicular to the bulb.

Edit: The magnet in the base actually rotates. I tested this by holding the bulb so that it cannot rotate.  The bulb remained floating which is impossible if the base magnet is static.

Comment: Sorry, this has been corrected now.